# Notification for When External Users Join

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, security, notifications

We have a few sites that require external access at the folder level. The external user has to be in Active Directory before adding to folder permissions so we created a new group 'External Users' and added a few in there. They do not show up in the group until the invite is accepted. Is there a way to be notified when an external user accepts a SharePoint Group invite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no OOB way to know when exactly an external user accepts an invitation. However, we can poll an Azure AD Security group every several minutes using a Power Automate flow. We can detect if there are any new members in a group since the last run.

This is a quick unfinished example, but should give you an idea of how to implement it:

[image]

I would create a SharePoint list that will store all processed external users. If an AD Security group has a new member that is not yet in the SharePoint list, then, we can send an email alert.

Answer (score 0):

**Please following steps:**

First, you have to create a **Microsoft 365 group** in Azure Active Directory

[image]

Then, sign in **Microsoft 365 admin center** as a global administrator. Navigation to **Groups**, and click **Active groups**, and find the newly created Microsoft 365 group.

Finally, click on the group. Then go to the "**Settings**" and turn on the "**Allow external senders to email this group**" option.

[image]

So, when you add an external user to the group, the external user will receive an invitation email.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't send a notification when user accepts